# react native passing params to other component

Tags: react-native, components, react-navigation

Hi I am new to react native and trying to learn few things. I am trying to pass a user name on a button click to child view. Here is my code on button click on view A

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('GetRegisteredScreen', {}, {
    type: ' Navigate',
    routeName: 'GetRegisteredScreen',
    params: {username: 'Robert'}
})
```

View B

```
componentDidMount(){
  alert(this.props.navigation.state.params.username)
}
```

Getting below error

> Undefined in the params.username

What am I doing wrong?

Can some one please help, Thanks in advance

EDIT: Here is the what I am getting for `this.props.navigation`

[image]

Comment: What do you get if you make a `console.log(this.props.navigation)`?

Comment: I have tested your code and it works fine. But I've changed `'Navigate'` instead of `' Navigate'`. Without the space.

Comment: I still get 'undefined' when i try to print out console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params.username).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your navigator injects the properties from params into the props of the next component, so just use

```
this.props.username
```

Comment: I have checked but its still not working. can you show me a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax mistake. You are passing the wrong. It should be like below.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate({
  routeName: 'GetRegisteredScreen',
  username: 'Robert'
});
// OR
this.props.navigation.navigate('GetRegisteredScreen', {
  username: 'Robert'
});
```

The syntax you are using is for [dispatching navigate action](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions#Navigate).

**Example**

```
const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
  routeName: 'Profile',
  params: {},
  action: NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'SubProfileRoute'})
})

this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction)
```